# Swift: Assigning an object of type sub class to a variable of type base class with generics produces error

Tags: ios, swift, generics, inheritance

I want to assign a **sub class** (*TapWhatYouHearViewController*), that inherits from its **parent class** (*BaseLectureViewController*) with implementing the generic using **an inherited type** (*TapWhatYouHear*), to a variable of type **parent class** (*BaseLectureViewController*) with the generic of type **base class** (*Game*).

Swift procudes the following error:

> Swift:: Error: cannot assign value of type 'TapWhatYouHearViewController' to type 'BaseLectureViewController?'

I've read, that one solution e.g. in Java would be using a wildcard generic, but this is not possible in Swift. **Is there any other solution?**

---

*This is my setup:*

```swift
/** GAME TYPES **/

enum GameType {
    case TapWhatYouHear,
    case ChooseTranslation
}

class Game {
    var title: String?
    var type: GameType?
}

class TapWhatYouHear : Game {
    var audio: String?
    var type: GameType = GameType.TapWhatYouHear
}

class ChooseTranslation : Game {
    var video: String?
    var type: GameType = GameType.ChooseTranslation
}

/** VIEW CONTROLLERS **/

class BaseLectureViewController<T: Game> {
   var game: T?
}

class TapWhatYouHearViewController : BaseLectureViewController<TapWhatYouHear> {

}

class ChooseTranslationViewController : BaseLectureViewController<ChooseTranslation> {

}
```

*I want to do the following:*

```swift
var game: Game = TapWhatYouHear() // <-- Depending on the user interaction, this can be any sub class of "Game"
var viewController: BaseLectureViewController<Game>

switch game.type {
    case .ChooseTranslation:
        viewController = TapWhatYouHearViewController() // <--Swift:: Error: cannot assign value of type 'TapWhatYouHearViewController' to type 'BaseLectureViewController<Game>?'
    case .TapWhatYouHear:
        viewController = ChooseTranslationViewController()
}

viewController.game = TapWhatYouHear()
```

---

What I'm trying to do is determine at runtime which sub class of `BaseLectureViewController` should be assigned to the `viewController` variable. To save code, I then want to assign a game of type `Game` to the `game` property of the `BaseLectureViewController`.

Comment: Is it necessary for you to use generics? What are you trying to do, perhaps there's an easier way?

Comment: For `ChooseTranslationViewController` class you specify that `game` property should be `ChooseTranslation`, so why later you want to assign `TapWhatYouHear` to `game` property? But if you are ok to know only about `title` property of `Game` class inside `ChooseTranslationViewController` you can implement property as `var game: Game`  instead of using Generics

Comment: @mag_zbc @Saik0s : I updated my question. Please look at the code and explaination at the bottom.
@Saik0s : My question is not about the specific type of `Game` but rather about assigning the specific view controller to a variable of type parent class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The generic approach you have in mind is not possible. My suggestion is to go with a simple inheritance solution where you override `getGame()` in your concrete ViewController (i.e. `TapWhatYouHearViewController`) and cast the game to your specific type.

```swift
import UIKit

enum GameType {
    case TapWhatYouHear
    case ChooseTranslation
}

class Game {
    var title: String?
    var type: GameType?
}

class TapWhatYouHear : Game {
    var audio: String?

    override init() {
        super.init()
        type = GameType.TapWhatYouHear
    }
}

class ChooseTranslation : Game {
    var video: String?

    override init() {
        super.init()
        type = GameType.ChooseTranslation
    }
}


/** VIEW CONTROLLERS **/



protocol Lecture {
    var game: Game? { get set }
}

class BaseLectureViewController: UIViewController, Lecture {

    var game: Game?
    func getGame() -> Game? {
        fatalError("Must be implemented in subclass")
    }
}

class TapWhatYouHearViewController : BaseLectureViewController {
    override func getGame() -> TapWhatYouHear? {
        return game as? TapWhatYouHear
    }
}

class ChooseTranslationViewController : BaseLectureViewController {
    override func getGame() -> ChooseTranslation? {
        return game as? ChooseTranslation
    }
}

var game: Game = TapWhatYouHear() // <-- Depending on the user interaction, this can be any sub class of "Game"
var viewController: BaseLectureViewController?

if let gameType = game.type {
    switch gameType {
    case GameType.ChooseTranslation:
        viewController = TapWhatYouHearViewController() // <--Swift:: Error: cannot assign value of type 'TapWhatYouHearViewController' to type 'BaseLectureViewController<Game>?'
    case GameType.TapWhatYouHear:
        viewController = ChooseTranslationViewController()
    }

    viewController?.game = TapWhatYouHear()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the variable declaration to

```
var viewController: BaseLectureViewController<TapWhatYouHear>
```

Or skip generics and declare your super class as

```
class BaseLectureViewController {
    var game: Game?
}
```

Comment: I updated the code under "I want to do the following". The `var viewController: BaseLectureViewConroller<Game>` part is required, since I will determine in the next lines of code which sub class type I want to assign to the `viewController` variable.

Comment: I think you need to declare it as above unless you want to cast the `game` property every time you need to access a subclass specific property or function

Comment: That would be no problem for me, since I don't need to access any specific properties of the `game` property. All I want to do is assign a subclass to its parent class and assign the variable `game`

Comment: See comment from @mag_zbc, I was going to ask the same

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is to assign a `game` property with an instance of specific subclass of `Game`, then you might use something like this, omitting generics

```
class Game {
    var title: String?

    required init() {}
}

class TapWhatYouHear : Game {
    var audio: String?
}

class ChooseTranslation : Game {
    var video: String?
}

/** VIEW CONTROLLERS **/

class BaseLectureViewController : UIViewController {
    var game: Game

    init(gameType: Game.Type)
    {
        game = gameType.init()
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

class TapWhatYouHearViewController : BaseLectureViewController{
    init()
    {
        super.init(gameType: TapWhatYouHear.self)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

class ChooseTranslationViewController : BaseLectureViewController{
    init()
    {
        super.init(gameType: ChooseTranslation.self)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

usage

```
var viewController : BaseLectureViewController
viewController = TapWhatYouHearViewController()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This seems plausible. How would the `init()` functions of the sub classes of `BaseLectureViewController` have to change, if `BaseLectureViewController` inherits from `UIViewController`?